# Buscador en tiempo real

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, postgresql, buscador

Estoy tratando de realizar un buscador en tiempo real, pero al hacer la búsqueda omite uno de los registros de la tabla, es decir, que si mi resultado de registros es 8 solo me va a mostrar 7.

Este es mi codigo php

```php
require_once("Base_Datos/con_personal.php");
session_start();

    $salida= "";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['b'])){
        $contenido=$_REQUEST['b'];
        //$contenido=json_encode($contenido);
        $sql="SELECT p.nombre, 
    p.apellido, 
    p.departamento, 
    p.cedula, 
    p.usuario_reg, 
    p.fecha_reg, 
    p.nombre_usuar, 
    p.idpersonal, 
    p.estatus, 
    est.desc_estatus, 
    asige.descrip_asignacion, 
    p.departamentos, 
    dep.descripcion, 
    p.estatusasignacion
   FROM personal p
   JOIN estatus est ON est.cod_estatus = p.estatus
   JOIN asig_equipos asige ON asige.cod_asig = p.estatusasignacion
   JOIN departamentos dep ON dep.cod = p.departamentos
   WHERE nombre ILIKE '%$contenido%' 
  ";

 $resultPag=pg_query($con,$sql);
 $ver=pg_fetch_array($resultPag);
 $mostrar=pg_num_rows($resultPag);
    $datos=$ver[7]."||".
           $ver[3]."||".
           $ver[0]."||". 
           $ver[1]."||".
           $ver[6]."||". 
           $ver[12]."||".
           $ver[4]."||".
           $ver[9]."||".
           $ver[10];
 //echo $ver;
if ($mostrar>0){
    $salida.="<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover' id='tabla_datosb'>
                  <tr>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-list-alt'></i>Cedula</th>
                  <th><i class='icon_profile'></i>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellido</th>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-check'></i>Nombre de Usuario</th>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-cubes'></i>Departamento</th>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-check'></i>Estatus</th>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-cloud-upload icon-3x'></i>Usuario de carga</th>
                  <th><i class='fa fa-check'></i>Estatus de Equipos</th>
                  <th>Editar</th>
                  <th>Eliminar</th>
                  </tr>";


    while ($fila = pg_fetch_assoc($resultPag)) {
                    $salida.="<tr>
                  <td>".$fila['cedula']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['apellido']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['nombre_usuar']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['desc_estatus']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['usuario_reg']."</td>  
                  <td>".$fila['descrip_asignacion']."</td>
                  <td>
                  <button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='editardatos(".$datos.")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaleditar'><i class='fa fa-gears'></i></button>
                    <div class='modal fade' id='modaleditar' tabindex='1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
                      <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                       <div class='modal-content'>
                         <div class='modal-header'>
                          <h4 class='modal-title' id='abrirModalP'>Editar datos</h4>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <form class='form-horizontal'  autocomplete='on'>
                          <div class='modal-body'>
                            <input id='idE' name='idE' type='hidden' value=''>

                            <label>Cedula</label>
                            <input type='text' name='cedulaE' id='cedulaE' class='form-control input-sm' value='' onkeypress='return solonumeros(event)' required maxlength='10' onpaste='return false'>
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type='text' name='nombreE' id='nombreE' class='form-control input-sm' value='' maxlength='25' required>
                            <label>Apellido</label>
                            <input type='text' name='apellidoE' id='apellidoE' class='form-control input-sm' maxlength='25' value='' required>
                            <label>Nombre de Usuario</label>
                            <br>
                            <input type='text' name='usuarioE' id='usuarioE' style='text-transform: uppercase;' onkeyup='javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'' value='' required>
                            <br>

                            <label>Departamento</label>
                             <select class='form-control m-bot15' name='departamentoeditp' id='departamentoeditp' >
                            </select>
                            <input type='hidden' name='departamentoE' id='departamentoE' value=".$fila['descripcion'].">

                            <!--Usuario de Carga-->
                            <input type='hidden' name='usuariocargaE' id='usuariocargaE' class='form-control input-sm' value=".$_SESSION['Usuario']." >
                            <label>Estatus</label>
                            <select class='form-control m-bot15' name='estatusep' id='estatusep' >
                              </select>
                            <input type='hidden' name='estatuseditadop' id='estatuseditadop' value=".$fila['desc_estatus']." >

                              <label>Estatus de Asignacion</label>
                            <select class='form-control m-bot15' name='estatusasig' id='estatusasig'>
                              </select>
                              <input type='hidden' name='estatusasigedit' id='estatusasigedit' value=".$fila['descrip_asignacion'].">
                          </div>
                          <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'  id='guardareditar' >Editar</button>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Volver</button>
                          </div>  
                       </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                   <td> <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='preguntarsino(".$ver[7].")'> <i class='fa fa-times icon-3x'></i></button>
                  </td> 
                  </tr>";
              }
                  $salida.="</table>
                  ";
} else {
    $salida.= "No se encontraron resultados";

}

}

echo $salida;
```

Luego de que realiza la consulta y encuentra resultados deberia mostrar todos los registros, si encuentra resultados crea la nueva tabla y la coloca la tabla principal de mi index, si no hay nada escrito en el buscador debería mostrar la tabla principal como siempre tal y como se coloca en el js.

Mi codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buscador_general").keyup(function(){
              var parametros=$("#buscador_general").val();
              console.log(parametros);
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "controlarvistas.php",
                    data: "b="+parametros,
                   // dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    //imagen de carga
                   // $("#resultado").html("<p align='center'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("error petición ajax");
                    },
                    success: function(data){                                                    
                    //console.log(data);
                    //$("#resultado").empty();
                    //$("#resultado").append(data); 

                      if (data !="" && data != null ) {
                        $("table#tabla_datos").hide();
                        $("#tabla").html(data);
                      } else{
                        $("table#tabla_datos").show();
                      } 
                      var parametros="";       
                      console.log(parametros);                                     
                    }
              });                               
         });
    //var buscador= $("imput#buscador_general").val();
    //console.log(buscador);
});
```

y mi index .php

```html
<?php
include('header.php');
require_once("Base_Datos/con_personal.php");
/*if (!session_start()){
session_start();
}*/
?>
<?php
if(!$_GET){

  $pag=1;
}else{
     $pag=$_GET['paginas'];
}

?>

    <!--main content start-->
     <div class="container">
   <div id="tab_personal"></div>

</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li><h3><i class="fa fa-group"></i>Personal</h3></a></li>
              <div id="tabla"></div>
              <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" id="tabla_datos">
                <tr> 
                  <th><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>Cedula</th>
                  <th><i class="icon_profile"></i>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Apellido</th>
                  <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Nombre de Usuario</th>
                  <th><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>Departamento</th>
                  <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Estatus</th>
                  <th><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload icon-3x"></i>Usuario de carga</th>
                  <th><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Estatus de Equipos</th>
                  <th>Editar</th>
                  <th>Eliminar</th>
                </tr>

               <?php
                    $obviarregistros=($pag-1)*8;
                    if ($obviarregistros==0){
                     $sql="SELECT * from vistap  limit 8";
                     $result=pg_query($con,$sql);
                    } 
                   else{

                     $sql="SELECT * from vistap offset $obviarregistros limit 8";
                    $result=pg_query($con,$sql);
                   }



                     $sql="SELECT * from vistap";
                    $resultPag=pg_query($con,$sql);
                     $totalarticulos=pg_num_rows($resultPag);
                       $registrosxpagina=8;    
                       $paginas=($totalarticulos/8); 
                       $paginas=ceil($paginas);


                       $nro =0;
                     while($ver=pg_fetch_array($result)){

                       $nro ++;

                        $datos=$ver[7]."||".
                               $ver[3]."||".
                               $ver[0]."||". 
                               $ver[1]."||".
                               $ver[6]."||". 
                               $ver[12]."||".
                               $ver[4]."||".
                               $ver[9]."||".
                               $ver[10];

                     ?>

                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['cedula'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['nombre'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['apellido'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['nombre_usuar'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['descripcion'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['desc_estatus'] ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $ver['usuario_reg'] ?></td>  
                  <td><?php echo $ver['descrip_asignacion'] ?></td>
                  <!-- Modal para editar-->
                  <td>
```

Tampoco logro retornar a la tabla principal que tenia antes de realizar la búsqueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
$ver=pg_fetch_array($resultPag);
```

Estas leyendo la primera fila del resultado antes de iterar.  Simplemente borra esa linea y veras todos los resultados.

Comment: Y para retornar a la tabla que tenia inicialmente?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, pero esa es la solucion a tu problema, no puedes leer la primera linea si quieres desplegar todos los resultados con el while.

Comment: En esta linea trato de ejecutar una función.js la cual me permite llenar los campos del formulario de mi modal, pero debido a que esta dentro de codigo php no lo ejecuta <button class='btn btn-warning' onclick='editardatos(".$datos.")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modaleditar'><i class='fa fa-gears'></i></button>